# Table not displaying until clicked when a CellPainterWrapper instead of a TextPainter for columns

Tags: java, nattable

I would like to add dynamic icons to column headers. To do this I've created a class that extends `CellPainterWrapper` and added a `CellPainterDecorator` with a `TextPainter` as the base painter and my dynamic icon painter as the decorator painter.

If I then swap the `CELL_PAINTER` in the config to use my class instead of the `TextPainter` the table doesn't display. If I click on where a row should be it then resizes and displays the table as expected with the column header text and icons. 
I've also tried using the `SortableHeaderTextPainter` and get the same issue occur.

```
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_PAINTER, new SortableHeaderTextPainter(),
    DisplayMode.NORMAL, GridRegion.COLUMN_HEADER);
```

Overall this means there is something different with how `TextPainter` and `SortableHeaderTextPainter` is implemented. In particular I can see parts in `TextPainter` that will call commands to resize the layer but I'm struggling to figure out how this should be done.

What needs to be added for it to set the initial column/row sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Either set the initial widths and heights via `DataLayer` or configure the `TextPainter` to calculate the dimensions. Either via setter or constructor parameter.

Comment: I've tried setting `calculate` to `true` with the same result with `new SortableHeaderTextPainter(new TextPainter(false, true, true))`

Comment: Without more information on your composition and configuration I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by one any of the painters having `paintBg` set to true and by my style not specifying the background color. No exceptions would be thrown but it would cause my table to not resize automatically.

To fix this I can either set `paintBg` to false for all of my painters or set the background color in the style.

Comment: So it means you have not configured the `DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration` that contains the basic necessary style configurations. Correct?

Comment: I'm not using the `DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration` as I'm using custom styles depending on the layer. I was then overwriting any existing styles by creating a new one and adding it as the cell style. 
Would it be more recommended to use the default config and instead of creating new styles, get the existing style config attribute and change the values in that?

Comment: If you want to completely use custom styles in every layer I would suggest to create a custom theme configuration by extending the default and exchanging the values. This way you have the style configuration in one place and can even exchange it easily at runtime.

Comment: That's a great idea. Thank you for the help!

Comment: This example should help learning about NatTable `ThemeConfiguration`s: https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_400_Configuration/_423_ThemeStylingExample.java